# How much of the Borg collective did Lore control?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

In the Star Trek TNG episode "Descent" (part 1 and 2), Lore exploits a weakened state of the Borg collective to become their leader (temporarily).

How much of the collective followed him? I infer that it was only a small portion but it's not necessarily clear in the episode.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a dupe. The first question asks whether the whole of the borg were infected by Hugh's individuality. This one is specifically asks how many followers Lore has in Descent Part 1. My answer notes that there has been significant wastage between the two events.

Comment: @Richard It is a dupe because it already has an answer on that question (which is exactly what the header added to the question says, when closed as a duplicate).  You answered it over there: "It only spread as far as Hugh's ship and no farther", and "probably numbering less than a few hundred", same as you answered here

Comment: @Izkata - Yes, but this question asks about the number that Lore took control of, not the number that were originally infected. Note that Hugh says that "many" of them died before Lore turned up. It's a subtle distinction but a distinction nonetheless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It's not made clear and the script doesn't say.**

In [TNG : I, Borg](http://tng.trekcore.com/episodes/scripts/223.txt), Hugh's body was reclaimed by a Borg "rescue vessel". There's no immediate evidence that his individuality spread any farther than that ship (into the wider Collective) and the crew complement of a rescue vessel isn't canonically confirmed.

- We actually see 27 individual borg in the two episodes plus there must be at least one on the ship that attacks the Enterprise. This sets the lower bound at at least 28, plus the number that have died (see Hugh's statements below).
- A Borg 'Rescue' vessel would likely have no more than a few hundred drones as crew (**conjecture**)
- Based on the size of the hall on the surface and the size of the ship in orbit, those could comfortably accomodate a couple of hundred drones (**conjecture**)

On top of that, there's been some wastage.

- The Borg have lost the ability (and desire) to assimilate their victims. Any casualties are unlikely to have been replaced.
- Hugh says that "many" of the drones on his ship died of starvation and infighting.
- Lore has apparently been experimenting on the remaining Borg, killing several in the process.

**My guess - no more than 100.**